# How to display current element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this sample:

[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEqNwV)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="clasa-comuna">
  <div class="declansare">
    <span class="plus">+</span>
    <span class="minus">-</span>
  </div>
  <div class="arata"></div>
</div>
<div class="clasa-comuna">
  <div class="declansare">
    <span class="plus">+</span>
    <span class="minus">-</span>
  </div>
  <div class="arata"></div>
</div>
<div class="clasa-comuna">
  <div class="declansare">
    <span class="plus">+</span>
    <span class="minus">-</span>
  </div>
  <div class="arata"></div>
</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.declansare{
  background:red;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
}
.arata{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:blue;
  display:none;
}
.clasa-comuna{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:10px;
}
.minus{
  display:none;
  color:white;
}
.plus{
  color:white;
}
```

**CODE JS:**

```
$( ".plus" ).on( "click", function() {
  $(this).closest('.clasa-comuna').find('arata').show();


  });
```

What I want to do is to display div `"arata"` It is the current element.

I tried something like 'but it displays all divs.

```
 $(".arata").toggle();
```

How can I solve this problem?

I hope I managed to make myself understood ... if you need more explanations are available.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

back with a question, I managed to make it work
but how to do only one to remain open?

[new link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEqNwV)

**CODE JS:**

```
$( ".plus" ).on( "click", function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).closest('.clasa-comuna').find('.arata').show();
  $(this).next().show();
});
```

I want to do just to remain at current open, not be able to open more than one ...

**EDIT 2:**

[new link 3](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEqNwV)

I'm near the end ... there is only one problem.
It remains in other mass minus sign before ... it is not allowed to exist than a minus ... at open

**CODE JS:**

```
$( ".plus" ).on( "click", function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $('.arata').hide();
  //$('.arata').hide();
  $(this).closest('.clasa-comuna').find('.arata').show();
  $(this).next().show();
});

$( ".minus" ).on( "click", function() {


});
```

Comment: missing the `.` for the class in `find` = `$(this).closest('.clasa-comuna').find('.arata').show();`

Comment: call `$(".arata").hide();` before calling `show`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax issue related to the selection used, you need to find the elements relative to the current element.

Another simple approach is to use a class to set the visibility like

```js
$(".plus, .minus").on("click", function() {
  var $comuna = $(this).closest('.clasa-comuna').toggleClass('open', $(this).hasClass('plus'));
  $('.clasa-comuna.open').not($comuna).removeClass('open');
});
```

```css
.declansare {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
.arata {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  display: none;
}
.clasa-comuna {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.clasa-comuna .minus {
  display: none;
  color: white;
}
.clasa-comuna .plus {
  color: white;
}
.clasa-comuna.open .minus {
  display: inline;
}
.clasa-comuna.open .plus {
  display: none;
}
.clasa-comuna.open .arata {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clasa-comuna">
  <div class="declansare">
    <span class="plus">+</span>
    <span class="minus">-</span>
  </div>
  <div class="arata"></div>
</div>
<div class="clasa-comuna">
  <div class="declansare">
    <span class="plus">+</span>
    <span class="minus">-</span>
  </div>
  <div class="arata"></div>
</div>
<div class="clasa-comuna">
  <div class="declansare">
    <span class="plus">+</span>
    <span class="minus">-</span>
  </div>
  <div class="arata"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following JQuery will make only one open.

```
$( ".plus" ).on( "click", function() {
  $('.arata').hide();
  $(this).closest('.clasa-comuna').find('.arata').show();
});
```

Hide all other before open div.

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xn3hk0n5/)**

**Edit:**

As per your required here i edited my answer.

```
$( ".plus" ).on( "click", function() {

  $('.arata').hide();
  $('.minus').hide();
  $('.plus').show();
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).closest('.clasa-comuna').find('.arata').show();
  $(this).next().show();
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xn3hk0n5/1/)**

Comment: @Marius Hope your issue solved. Please don't forget to accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

change CODE JS like this

$( ".plus" ).on( "click", function() {
  $(this).parent().find('.arata').show();

});

you have to put "." ahead of arata,if arata is class of div, if arata is id then put '#'